# Custom SVG marker, dependent on data

Tags: highcharts

I can add a custom SVG element to a chart like the *wind arrows* in the [meteogram example](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/combo-meteogram/). Note how the look of each individual wind arrow is customized with the parameters (a) wind speed and (b) direction.

I can also place custom SVG markers on to a series like the `cross` in the [custom markers demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/series-marker-symbol/).

The latter approach has the advantage that if I have a zoom-able chart (Highstock) the markers will stay where they are supposed to be when zooming/panning. However, the latter example does not allow parameter dependent customization of the SVG marker!

Is there a way to combine these two? As in, I want custom SVG markers, that are bound to the series but whose shape is determined by other external parameters.

Comment: I preared simple demo, based on highstock (http://jsfiddle.net/z5j39tmq/2/) so please let me know if these markers should be "scaled" or somehting different?

Comment: Thanks for taking a shot at this Sebastian. I have reduced and extended your fiddle to draw an actual arrow. (http://jsfiddle.net/cpL73p47/). The arrow's `fillColor` should be dependent on the value of the "Wind Speed" series by using the supplied function `getColorBySpeed(speed)`. Additionally, the arrow should be rotated into the corresponding wind direction as given by the other series "Wind Direction".

Comment: You can use a rotation like in meteogram, but fill color like here: http://jsfiddle.net/cpL73p47/3/

Comment: Nice, but I still don't see how I can rotate the `SVGElement` because I don't seem to be able to access it from within the callback function. In the callback function I'm dealing with `Point` objects, but I really need to call the `attr({rotation: ...})` method on the `SVGElement` that is the rendered marker of this `Point`.

Comment: You need to use tranform function and then call rotate inside. http://jsfiddle.net/cpL73p47/4/

Comment: That's it, `p.graphic` was the missing link! Thanks so much

Comment: Sebastian, in your last example the arrows are fully set up the way I want them. However, now when the chart is being resized the arrows are moving away from their original Y-position. Hard to explain but you will see it when you resize the chart.

Comment: I placed rotation in incorrect place, sorry. Fixed: http://jsfiddle.net/cpL73p47/7/